# Как анимировать svg изображение в формате Fig?

Tags: svg

Всем доброго времени суток помогите пожалуйста разобраться с SVG анимацией. Мне нужно анимировать svg файл на котором изображена лампа внутри которой находиться круг с прерывистой линией. Как сделать так что бы круг вращался и светился на подобии этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg width="597" height="477" viewBox="0 0 597 477" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<ellipse cx="319.5" cy="419" rx="65.5" ry="24" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path d="M384 419C384 421.916 382.391 424.82 379.198 427.586C376.008 430.349 371.334 432.884 365.471 435.032C353.755 439.325 337.501 442 319.5 442C301.499 442 285.245 439.325 273.529 435.032C267.666 432.884 262.992 430.349 259.802 427.586C256.609 424.82 255 421.916 255 419C255 416.084 256.609 413.18 259.802 410.414C262.992 407.651 267.666 405.116 273.529 402.968C285.245 398.675 301.499 396 319.5 396C337.501 396 353.755 398.675 365.471 402.968C371.334 405.116 376.008 407.651 379.198 410.414C382.391 413.18 384 416.084 384 419Z" stroke="#F0E8E8" stroke-opacity="0.56" stroke-width="2"/>
<g filter="url(#filter1_b)">
<ellipse cx="319.5" cy="419" rx="63.5" ry="22" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<ellipse cx="319.5" cy="419" rx="63.5" ry="22" fill="url(#pattern0)" fill-opacity="0.08" style="mix-blend-mode:overlay"/>
<path d="M319.5 442C337.116 442 353.107 439.528 364.729 435.501C370.535 433.49 375.305 431.072 378.644 428.337C381.975 425.608 384 422.459 384 419C384 415.541 381.975 412.392 378.644 409.663C375.305 406.928 370.535 404.51 364.729 402.499C353.107 398.472 337.116 396 319.5 396C301.884 396 285.893 398.472 274.271 402.499C268.465 404.51 263.695 406.928 260.356 409.663C257.025 412.392 255 415.541 255 419C255 422.459 257.025 425.608 260.356 428.337C263.695 431.072 268.465 433.49 274.271 435.501C285.893 439.528 301.884 442 319.5 442Z" stroke="url(#paint2_radial)" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="2"/>
<path d="M319.5 442C337.116 442 353.107 439.528 364.729 435.501C370.535 433.49 375.305 431.072 378.644 428.337C381.975 425.608 384 422.459 384 419C384 415.541 381.975 412.392 378.644 409.663C375.305 406.928 370.535 404.51 364.729 402.499C353.107 398.472 337.116 396 319.5 396C301.884 396 285.893 398.472 274.271 402.499C268.465 404.51 263.695 406.928 260.356 409.663C257.025 412.392 255 415.541 255 419C255 422.459 257.025 425.608 260.356 428.337C263.695 431.072 268.465 433.49 274.271 435.501C285.893 439.528 301.884 442 319.5 442Z" stroke="url(#paint3_radial)" stroke-opacity="0.6" stroke-width="2"/>
</g>
<ellipse cx="319.5" cy="410.5" rx="34.5" ry="11.5" fill="#6AAAB6" fill-opacity="0.75"/>
<g filter="url(#filter2_b)">
<path d="M348 409.5C348 410.359 347.459 411.349 346.076 412.402C344.708 413.443 342.666 414.424 340.053 415.266C334.838 416.945 327.571 418 319.5 418C311.429 418 304.162 416.945 298.947 415.266C296.334 414.424 294.292 413.443 292.924 412.402C291.541 411.349 291 410.359 291 409.5C291 408.641 291.541 407.651 292.924 406.598C294.292 405.557 296.334 404.576 298.947 403.734C304.162 402.055 311.429 401 319.5 401C327.571 401 334.838 402.055 340.053 403.734C342.666 404.576 344.708 405.557 346.076 406.598C347.459 407.651 348 408.641 348 409.5Z" stroke="#8BD6E7" stroke-opacity="0.48" stroke-width="2"/>
<path d="M346.75 409.5C346.75 410.403 346.076 411.324 344.703 412.209C343.342 413.087 341.356 413.887 338.88 414.562C333.93 415.912 327.078 416.75 319.5 416.75C311.922 416.75 305.07 415.912 300.12 414.562C297.644 413.887 295.658 413.087 294.297 412.209C292.924 411.324 292.25 410.403 292.25 409.5C292.25 408.597 292.924 407.676 294.297 406.791C295.658 405.913 297.644 405.113 300.12 404.438C305.07 403.088 311.922 402.25 319.5 402.25C327.078 402.25 333.93 403.088 338.88 404.438C341.356 405.113 343.342 405.913 344.703 406.791C346.076 407.676 346.75 408.597 346.75 409.5Z" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M348.75 409.5C348.75 410.698 347.996 411.883 346.53 412.999C345.069 414.112 342.938 415.124 340.283 415.98C334.975 417.689 327.627 418.75 319.5 418.75C311.372 418.75 304.025 417.689 298.717 415.98C296.062 415.124 293.931 414.112 292.47 412.999C291.004 411.883 290.25 410.698 290.25 409.5C290.25 408.302 291.004 407.117 292.47 406.001C293.931 404.888 296.062 403.876 298.717 403.02C304.025 401.311 311.372 400.25 319.5 400.25C327.627 400.25 334.975 401.311 340.283 403.02C342.938 403.876 345.069 404.888 346.53 406.001C347.996 407.117 348.75 408.302 348.75 409.5Z" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M318.5 419L319 416.5H321L321.5 419H320H319.5H318.5Z" fill="#D9D5D5"/>
<path d="M290.5 408.5L292.5 409L292.558 409.032C292.563 409.006 292.567 409.003 292.567 409.037L292.5 409.5L292.567 409.957L292.5 410L290.5 411C290.348 411.076 290.201 410.716 290.107 410.407L290.031 409.957C290.031 409.957 289.978 409.363 290.031 409C290.138 408.5 290.249 408.5 290.5 408.5Z" fill="#D9D5D5"/>
<path d="M348.953 409.019H346.394L346.5 409.5L346.394 410L348.671 410.945L348.7 410.871L348.728 410.797L348.75 410.734C348.841 410.602 348.953 410.368 348.953 410.275L349 410V409.5V409.25L348.953 409.019Z" fill="#D9D5D5"/>
<path d="M319 402.5L318.5 400H321.5L321 402.5H320H319Z" fill="#D9D5D5"/>
</g>
<path d="M324.85 410.5C324.85 410.634 324.759 410.793 324.52 410.962C324.286 411.128 323.937 411.284 323.492 411.417C322.605 411.683 321.37 411.85 320 411.85C318.63 411.85 317.395 411.683 316.508 411.417C316.063 411.284 315.714 411.128 315.48 410.962C315.241 410.793 315.15 410.634 315.15 410.5C315.15 410.366 315.241 410.207 315.48 410.038C315.714 409.872 316.063 409.716 316.508 409.583C317.395 409.317 318.63 409.15 320 409.15C321.37 409.15 322.605 409.317 323.492 409.583C323.937 409.716 324.286 409.872 324.52 410.038C324.759 410.207 324.85 410.366 324.85 410.5Z" stroke="#F0E8E8" stroke-opacity="0.85" stroke-width="0.3"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="-4" y="0" width="605" height="485" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter1_b" x="204" y="345" width="231" height="148" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="25"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0.153543) scale(0.00115486 0.00333333)"/>
</pattern>
<filter id="filter2_b" x="140" y="250" width="359" height="319" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="75"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="219.961" y1="389" x2="379.552" y2="431.763" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
<stop offset="0.40625" stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.9"/>
<stop offset="0.677083" stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0E8E8" stop-opacity="0.9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0E8E8" stop-opacity="0.85"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="397" y1="404.5" x2="262" y2="429.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
<stop offset="0.40625" stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.9"/>
<stop offset="0.677083" stop-color="#CCCCCC" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0E8E8" stop-opacity="0.9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0E8E8" stop-opacity="0.85"/>
</linearGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint2_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(269 397) rotate(16.8763) scale(93.0054 268.447)">
<stop stop-color="#8BD6E7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#8BD6E7" stop-opacity="0.25"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint3_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(415 445) rotate(-156.218) scale(64.4748 91.5126)">
<stop stop-color="#F0E8E8" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0E8E8"/>
</radialGradient>
<image id="image0" width="600" height="300"
```

ссылка на SVG [`тут`](https://codepen.io/avdoshka/pen/YzZWJoq)
Желательно не использовать скрипты. Помогите пожалуйста это реализовать

Comment: там овалы .... сами понимаете что надо круг